# Auto-resizing the inside images if the div is starting to fill up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have this idea, to add an "Online Users" thingy to my site.
But I don't know how to do this thingy.

Let me explain. If there are online users, it'll show this on the div.

[image]

But if there are alot of online users, which is gonna crowd the div,
I want the images inside to automatically resize, to accomodate the
extra users. Anyone?

[image]

PS: I can't post images yet.

Comment: Can't the div containing the users grow instead of the users themselves shrinking? That will be way easier and will need just CSS.

Comment: I need the extra spaces of the page. And what's with the -1?

Comment: I don't want to make this... [link](http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/5435/143e0c4f1a204dd6a36aa22.png) Turn into this... [link](http://img541.imageshack.us/img541/5261/989ae9e6a54b4ad9a950e3e.png)

Comment: Check the answer I posted, that should get you started. BTW, i did not downvote your question, someone else did!

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/3KUvt/

The logic involves calculating the total available area in the beginning and calculating a new size (for each user element) whenever a new user is added.

Please note that this is a 2 minute fiddle and **will** need some fine tuning from your side before you can use this on production. :)

**Code:** *See the demo above to get the complete picture*

```
// can fit 8 of them without shrinking, so pre-calculate available area
var availableArea = 8 * 40 * 40;

function addUser() {

    // after adding the new one, how many will there be?
    var newCount = $('#holder > .user').length + 1;

    // calculate new dimension of each user
    var newW = 40; // use same var for w and h since its a square
    if(newCount > 8) {
        // reduce width (and height) till it fits
        while((newCount * newW * newW) > availableArea) {
            newW -= 1;
        }
    }

    // resize all existing users
    $('#holder > .user').css({
        width: newW + 'px',
        height: newW + 'px'
    });

    // add the new user (with the new height)
    $('<div class="user"><div>').css({
        width: newW + 'px',
        height: newW + 'px'
    }).appendTo('#holder');

}
```

Comment: exactly what I needed! Thank you for your answer techfoobar! :)